# Does the Dueling damage bonus not apply to Two-Handed Weapons?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, weapons, fighting-style

The Dueling fighting style is defined as following (PHB p 72):

> "When you are wielding a melee weapon **in one hand** and no other weapons, you gain a +2 bonus to damage rolls with that weapon"

Can I assume this means we do *not* get the +2 bonus when wielding two-handed weapons such as a pike, glaive or halberd?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65863/discussion-on-question-by-maadiah-does-dueling-preclude-use-of-two-handed-weapon).

Comment: Very related: [Does the Dueling fighting style work with versatile weapons while wielding them with two hands?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/159048/does-the-dueling-fighting-style-work-with-versatile-weapons-while-wielding-them)

Answer (score 31):

Being possessed of the Dueling fighting style doesn't *preclude* the use of a two-handed weapon. You can still use a two-handed weapon as you normally would.

However, when you do so you do not gain the bonus provided by Dueling as you no longer meet the prerequisite. *I.e.* as the weapon "requires two hands to use" (Weapon Properties, pp.146-147, at "Two-Handed") neither hand can *singly* be said to be wielding the weapon as the style would require.

Answer (score 18):

> Can I assume this means we do not get the +2 bonus when wielding two-handed weapons such as a pike, glaive or halberd?

Correct, because the character is now holding a melee weapon with two hands (ergo, **in two hands**). The character doesn't get a pass on this just because there is only one weapon entity. This is different from wielding a sword in one hand and a shield in another because only one of those counts as a weapon.

This also means that when they use the versatile feature of a battleaxe (changing a d8 to a d10), they lose the benefits of the dueling style because they're now gripping the weapon with two hands.

Answer (score -10):

Much of the discussion here depends if you interpret "in one hand" as meaning 'in at least one hand' or 'in only one hand.'

Without clarification I would assume the charitable interpretation of 'in at least one hand' meaning that two handed weapons would get the +2 damage modifier.  Just like weapon and shield, and one-handed weapon and empty hand (or rose, bottle, book in other hand).

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take the [tour] when you get the chance. Can you explain why you would assume that interpretation?

Comment: You can't wield a weapon with *no* hands (generally speaking), so if they meant it the way you interpret it, there'd be no need to mention hands at all. Seems like a solid argument against your interpretation to me.