# Does the Dueling fighting style work with versatile weapons while wielding them with two hands?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, fighting-style

The Dueling fighting style states that:

> When you are wielding a melee weapon in one hand and no other weapons, you gain a +2 bonus to damage rolls with that weapon.

I know that the versatile property doesn't disqualify it as it's not two-handed, but what about the "in one hand" part of the feat? Would you be able to wield a versatile weapon with two hands and still gain the benefits from Dueling?

Comment: Related: "[Does the Dueling damage bonus not apply to Two-Handed Weapons?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/76821)"

Answer (score 25):

When you are wielding a versatile weapon with two hands, you are not wielding it with one hand.

The text of Dueling states that it applies when you are wielding a melee weapon with one hand.  Therefore, it does not apply when you are wielding it with two hands.

This is also confirmed by [a tweet by rules designer Jeremy Crawford from April 2018](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/988948646895890432) (though those are no longer official):

> *planning on making a Samurai Fighter. Does the Dueling fighting style work for versatile weapons like a longsword?*
>
> **The Dueling fighting style works with a versatile weapon only when you attack with it using one hand.**

Comment: Of note, that if a feat or feature is added in the future that lets you wield a two-handed weapon in one hand (a la Titan's Grip form WoW), you could use Dueling with it. Probably not likely to happen outside of homebrew, but an interesting side effect of the wording.

Answer (score 11):

## No

As you quoted,

> When you are wielding a melee weapon **in one hand** and no other weapons, you gain a +2 bonus to damage rolls with that weapon.

This means that you have to be wielding the weapon in one hand. If you are wielding the weapon in both hands, you are not wielding it in one hand, and do not gain the +2 to damage.